# Socket io issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, backend

My code isn't logging any messages in my console, I need the code to log a message when I run my server

Server side

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Run when client connects
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //welcome current user
    socket.emit("message", 'Welcome to ChatApp');

    //Broadcast when a user connects
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'A user has join the chat');

    //Runs when client disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        io.emit('message', 'A user has left the chat')
    })
});

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}'));
```

Client side

```
const socket = io();

io.sockets.on("message", message =>{
    console.log("message")
})
```

its like as if the client side isnt functioning

Comment: Doesn't your client have to connect to the server first?

Comment: Please how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your client code.

You set up a variable named `socket` but then attempt to set a handler on `io.sockets`

**Change**:

```
const socket = io();

io.sockets.on("message", message =>{
    console.log("message")
})
```

**To**:

```
const socket = io();

socket.on("message", message =>{
    console.log("message")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the socket by providing required parameters like URL and the optional parameters if required

```
 socket = io('<SERVER_URL_HERE>', {
    reconnection: true, // optional
    reconnectionDelay: 1000, // optional
    reconnectionDelayMax : 25000, // optional
    reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, // optional
    autoConnect: true, // optional
    query:{isAgent,agentId,isCustomer,projectId} // optional
})
```